# when hanging an event on a block, how to change the required element

Tags: javascript, dom, delegation

I have a common container with id category, where there are cards with the same class. each card has a button to see the back of the card. I am hanging an event on a common block and I keep track of what was clicked. If this button is flipped, then I add classes. But when I press all the cards are flipped. How can I change the state of only a specific card that was clicked?
JS:

```
document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  if(e.target === document.querySelector('.turn-btn')) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.card-front').forEach(item => item.classList.add('front-rotate'));
    document.querySelectorAll('.card-back').forEach(item => item.classList.add('back-rotate'));
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="category">
  <div class="card card-item">
     <div class="card-front">
        <div class="card-image">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-desc">
           <div class="card-text"></div>
           <div class="turn"><span class="material-icons turn-btn">sync</span> 
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
         <div class="card-image">
           <img src=""></div>
         <div class="card-desc">
            <div class="card-text"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="card card-item">
     <div class="card-front">
        <div class="card-image">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-desc">
           <div class="card-text"></div>
           <div class="turn"><span class="material-icons turn-btn">sync</span> 
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
         <div class="card-image">
           <img src=""></div>
         <div class="card-desc">
            <div class="card-text"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<div class="card card-item">
     <div class="card-front">
        <div class="card-image">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-desc">
           <div class="card-text"></div>
           <div class="turn"><span class="material-icons turn-btn">sync</span> 
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
         <div class="card-image">
           <img src=""></div>
         <div class="card-desc">
            <div class="card-text"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
....
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Instead of using `querySelectorAll()`, you probably want to select the card associated with the clicked button: `e.target.closest('.card-front').classList.add('front-rotate')`. Do the same for `.card-back` class.

Comment: um, only select the card that is clicked instead of selecting them all?

Comment: `e.target.querySelectorAll('.card-front').forEach(...)`? Impossible to say for certain without knowing the structure of your HTML.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i added HTML

Comment: @Yousaf it will works with card-front, but in card-back, i haven't  turn-btn

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dummy example. Images are faked as div. The idea may be to use a background image for front and back, and flip cards using `classList.toggle`. In this dummy this is faked using a div element with certain classes. So, more css, less scripting and html.

```js
document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('click', flipDummy);

function flipDummy(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("turn-btn")) {
    // find the .card parent for this button
    const theCard = evt.target.closest(".card");

    if (theCard) {
      // toggle the .back-class
      theCard.querySelector(".cardImage").classList.toggle("back");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.cardImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.cardImage:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: "F R O N T";
  color: white;
  line-height: 125px;
}

.cardImage.back:before {
  color: yellow;
  content: "B A C K";
}

/* you'll need 52 classes, and a .back class
   that's 53 background-images. Or use an image sprite
   (see https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites) */
.first {
  background-image: /*url to image*/ none;
  background-color: #999;
}

.back {
  background-image: /*url to image*/ none;
  background-color: /*for demo*/ green;
}

.second {
  background-image: /*url to image*/ none;
  background-color: blue;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="category">
  <div class="card card-item">
    <div class="card-front">
      <div class="card-image">
        <!-- a fake card -->
        <div class="first cardImage"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-desc">
        <div class="card-text"></div>
        <div class="turn">
          <button class="material-icons turn-btn">sync</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-item">
    <div class="card-front">
      <div class="card-image">
        <!-- another fake card -->
        <div class="second cardImage"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-desc">
        <div class="card-text"></div>
        <div class="turn">
          <button class="material-icons turn-btn">sync</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```